# Google Cloud Messaging, registration handshake

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, cloud, google-cloud-platform, messaging

I've been looking everywhere for an answer to this, it says it goes something like server > GCM > client, the client must register and then it sends the registration token back to the server, but the 'client' part im confused about, does this only work on applications on the device? or can the app be on a website too? so for example if my app is a website, can I have the registration process on a website instead of an actual app on the device?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the currently listed client apps are Chrome, Android and iOS. Fortunately, you can use [Progressive Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/?hl=en) to handle push notifications to websites.

The usual prerequisites are listed there, such as creating the Google Developer Console project, and other PWA fundamental configurations (add, register, and install Service Workers). The succeeding steps are PWA-specific implementations for you to have push notification implemented on the web page.

Happy coding!